# Forming an SQL query that finds the total age of people who have 's' OR 'O' in their name out of a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]

as stated in the title, and this is the table, I know the query would start as something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE fullname LIKE ‘%s’ AND fullname LIKE ‘%O’;”
```

but struggling to workout the query for totalling the result of this..

Comment: Need two wildcards: `'%s%'`

Comment: Are you really using those double and single quotes? Are you using a word processor to create your code?

Comment: The double quotes might cause an issue...

Comment: No I use sublime, I was just playing around with it in word.

Comment: is there a command to check if a name contains lower case s and upper case O in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know how the total age of all those people that meet the criteria use `SUM()`

So

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(age) as total FROM users
        WHERE fullname LIKE '%s%' AND fullname LIKE '%O%'"
```

Now you just fetch the result and `total` is the total age of all the people that met your search criteria

I still think you will probably also need to change the AND to an OR like this, but you will have to play with it as its not totally clear from your question.

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(age) as total FROM users
        WHERE fullname LIKE '%s%' OR fullname LIKE '%O%'"
```

Comment: The OP wanted the names that had both an "s" and an "O" in the name, so they need to keep the `AND` rather than replacing it with `OR`.

Comment: thanks for your reply, seems to be getting there however I need the total age of the people, not the rows

Comment: Well in that case what is the age column called, and what data type is it?

Comment: says on the picture, it's just called 'age' and i assume is datatype INT but not sure how relevant that is

Comment: Ok, seen the image now. Amended the answer accordingly

Comment: @RiggsFolly Actually, I think the OP is confused, and you might very well be correct. Using the sample data, every single record would be excluded (using `AND`).

Comment: @PeterAbolins Thanks. I have covered both bases and left it up to the OP to decide

Comment: @PeterAbolins ah yeah, it's OR not AND, as you said every entry would be exlucded with AND, ill edit the question now. Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(age) as total_age
FROM users
WHERE fullname LIKE '%s%' OR fullname LIKE '%O%';
```

form first line we are selecting one column 'age' and applying apply function to add the ages and 'as total_age' will change the column name to 'total_age'

Then from second line we will select table name from where we are selecting column

and the last line is applying the condition to select the names in which 's' or 'o' exist.

**use of % :** when we don't know the multiple alphabets at that side we put %
but for the single alphabet that we dont know then we will us '_'(underscore).

Answer (score -1):

Use two wildcards with the character which you want to search

SELECT * FROM users WHERE fullname LIKE '%s%' AND fullname LIKE '%o%'